# .insertBefore doing nothing every fourth click

Tags: javascript, html

### Problem

I got a few simple lines of code, and just can't understand why `.insertBefore` isn't working every fourth click.

---

### HTML

```
<ul id="container">
    <li>1
    <li>2
    <li>3
</ul>
<button id="button">change</button>
```

---

### Javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', changeIt, false);

function changeIt(){
    // alert('hi'); (checked that function is running 4th time)
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var first = container.firstChild;
    var last = container.lastChild;
    container.insertBefore(last, first);
    // alert(last); >> shows last item is a text node every 4th time
}
```

---

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FuFtF/27/

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!..
The fourth time, insertBefore wasn't replacing an HTML element, but a text object.

I'll make sure to test if the variable is an HTML element with the nodeType like this:

```
// if it's an html element, the nodeType must be 1
// if it's not
if(last.nodeType !== 1){
    // remove it,
    last.remove();
    // again grab last item
    last = container.lastChild;
}
```

Comment: and whats that textnode is?

Comment: Don't know, but used alert(last); to find out it was a text node.

Comment: its giving `return(Enter)` arrow symbol in console, but dont know how is it coming